# Decimal point from number pad won't work on the calculator but will everywhere else

Tags: calculator

When I'm using the calculator under accessories on the Linux system, I have a number pad to the side of my keyboard I use most frequently and the decimal point will not work from the number pad on the calculator unless I use the regular "period" key from the keyboard.

All other functions will work (add, subtract, multiply, divide) and the decimal point works in excel, word, etc. but not for the calculator. I know someone wanted to change the decimal to a comma, but is there any way to make the decimal work?

Comment: Just to check: have you got NumLk on?

Comment: Nope, I didn't! Boy do I feel stupid! Thank you!!

Comment: Easy fix though! Just added as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure the keypad works, make sure that the "Num Lock" or "NumLk" key is pressed.